# AppleScript counter

Tags: applescript

I used to use this AppleScript for incrementing a counter every time I was running the script,
I tried to use again (from Keyboard maestro now) but the value remain to "1" no matter how many time I'm running it.

Any idea how can I fix it? I assume KM is recompiling every time I'm running which is causing the issue (I'm probably wrong though)

```
property today : missing value
property currentCount : 0


increment()

on increment()
    set currentDate to short date string of (current date)
    if currentDate is not today then
        set today to currentDate
        set currentCount to 0
    end if
    set currentCount to currentCount + 1
    
end increment
```

Comment: Perhaps I should call this script from KM instead of running it locally?

Comment: I do not have **Keyboard Maestro**, so I can't specifically help with it. However, if I run your _code_ in **Script Editor** it increments just fine.

Comment: Saved as an application, it increments just fine, even if it quits after each run. I can't test KM.

Comment: Write the value out to a file instead of using a persistent property